# Powershell enumerate interfaceindex from get-netadapter to set-dnsclientserveraddress

Tags: powershell, dns

I need to create a script that will update the dns server for network adapters in bulk.

So no matter what adapter is used, wired, wireless, etc... the DNS entries for the managed DNS service are always used.

I can't find a way to run get-netadapter and store the interfaceindex value in a variable/array and pipe the output to set-dnsclientserveraddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interfaceindex is accepted as valuefrompipeline both by value and name so you can just do:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name 'youradaptername' | 
  Set-DnsClientServerAddress  -ServerAddresses ('10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I thought I had tried this before (may be that I didn't launch powershell as admin):

get-netadapter | set-dnsclientserveraddress -ServerAddresses ("8.8.8.8","4.2.2.2") worked like a champ.

Thanks for the assist.